# How to force Asynctask to cancel without checking for isCancelled()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, tesseract

I have a specific command within my doInBackground() method that is long-lasting, ~20 seconds. Ideally I'd be able to interrupt it as soon as the user cancels the task, but since the program doesn't progress past that command until it completes, it ends up taking the ~20 seconds regardless. Here it is:

```
    String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

It's part of the tess-two OCR library, and it's the command that actually scans the image for text using the OCR algorithm. I have, after it,

```
if (myOCRTask.isCancelled()) {
    Log.i(TAG, "isCancelled() true.");
    return null;
}
```

And that works as expected, but I still want to be able to interrupt the task somehow in the midst of the OCR running. Is there any way to do this with Asynctask, or do I need to implement some other mechanism?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I should mention an additional issue that I'm having as a result of not being able to cancel the task in the expected timeframe.

If the user cancels the task, they have an opportunity to restart it using a new image, and in that case I call :

```
    myOCRTask = new OCRTask();
    myOCRTask.execute();
```

again. Now, in the original task (the original instantiation of myOCRTask), it eventually checks isCancelled() and if true, skips all subsequent instructions by returning null. However, it seems like because the first is still running, and because I'm re-instantiating it as a new instance of the same task, they're sharing a cancelled flag, and so onCancelled() is returning true even though the user cancelled it, and thus the first, still-running instance isn't skipping the steps I'd want it to skip. Make sense?

It occurs to me that in onPostExecute() I could check something like

```
if (myOCRTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)
```

Sound like it might work?

Comment: I guess you never looked at the documentation of `AsyncTask`. [**See this**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)).

Comment: if the OCR task is blocking, there's no way other than getting its source code and modifying it with for example a listener to ask if it's canceled.

Comment: @XaverKapeller AsyncTask.cancel() will only set the canceled flag to true which you later have to check with isCanceled.  He's looking for a direct termination of thread-  which is a very bad idea.

Comment: What Gabe said: unfortunately, it doesn't force-interrupt it as I'd originally expected, it just sets the cancelled flag to true.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do this-  ever.  Its not a safe thing to do.  You don't know what resources that library is using, and by canceling the thread on it you will cause it to not deallocate those resources.  At absolute best you'll have a large memory leak.  At worst, you'll put the library into a state where any further use will crash your app.  There's a reason why Java deprecated the stop thread functionality-  its not something you should ever do.

Instead what you should do is modify the library to occassinally check with you to see if its canceled, and if so exit safely.

Comment: afaik cancelling an AsyncTask just sets a flag, it doesn't kill the thread or otherwise interact with it.

Comment: @rupps Via the canceled call, yes.  I was talking about direct thread termination, which is what he wants.

Comment: hmm he wants to interrupt the task, the only way would be to modify the library and poll isCancelled. Directly terminating the asynctask thread? Is that even possible? (besides dangerous)

Comment: Interesting, thanks Gabe. I was a bit concerned about repercussions of that nature, but I'm not knowledgeable enough to really know what to expect, so thanks for answering a part of my question =) I'm going to edit my original question with a subsequent one, because it's a part of the issue I'm having.

Comment: @rupps It is possible to directly terminate a thread in Java, although the mechanism is deprecated and the docs say you should never use it (for good reason).  An AsyncTask is a thin wrapper around Thread.  There's no direct API for it, but if you could get a Thread handle you could do it.  If nothing else you could probably use reflection to get at one.  It may screw up the entire AsyncTask subsystem to try though.

Comment: wow that's like formatting the SDCARD to erase a camera picture. You'd definitely screw up the AsyncTask executor!

Comment: I wanted to stop it from utilizing the CPU for such a long period of time, especially since it's likely being re-started again quickly.